# Are insignificant variables included in calculation of predicted probabilities?

Tags: regression, logistic, predictive-models

When calculating the predicted probabilities in a logistic regression model, do we consider all the variables or just the significant ones? 
For eg: Let's say my model has: dependent variable Y and 3 dependent variables Xi out of which coefficients of X1 an X2 are significant whereas X3 is not significant. So for calculating the the predicted probabilities will I use just X1*beta1 + X2*beta2 or include X3*beta3 as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to exclude all nonsignificant parameters to choose the best model?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90899/is-it-necessary-to-exclude-all-nonsignificant-parameters-to-choose-the-best-mode)

Comment: Also [Should covariates that are not statistically significant be 'kept in' when creating a model?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66448/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That question was asked and answered here: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/450768-calculation-of-predicted-probabilities